# Custom Magento 2 module doesn't seem to recognize any files after registration.php (MagentoEE ver. 2.1.9)

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1.9

I'm attempting to create my first module for Magento 2. This module will be my own version of "hello world". I'm simply attempting to add "test" to a product page. Currently I'm attempting to target just after the add to cart button due to the abundance of tutorials.

So far I have:
Namespace/MyPlugin/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_MyPlugin',
    __DIR__
);
```

and Namespace/MyPlugin/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_MyPlugin" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

At this point I setup and enabled the module (per the tutorial). It shows up under registered modules now.

Now, I suspect the problem may be before this next file as I can put blatant XML errors in this file and it still loads the page without throwing an exception. Read, nothing I purposefully add to this page to get a reaction changes anything.

Namespace/MyPlugin/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Namespace\MyPlugin\Block\Catalog\Product\Myplugin"
                    name="product.info.Colorswatches"
                    template="Namespace_MyPlugin::catalog/product/myplugin.phtml"
                    after="-">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I also have files created for the two files declared in the catalog_product_view.xml but again I can throw PHP die(); into them and it seemingly never gets loaded.

Namespace/MyPlugin/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/myplugin.phtml
Namespace/MyPlugin/Block/Catalog/Product/Myplugin.php

It's also worth noting I'm new to Magento 2 in general and this could be compilation issues as I'm still not overly familiar with when I need to build, etc.